# Cannot get ui_guage to display each message after specified delay time

Tags: user-interface, ibm-cloud, dashboard, node-red, tone-analyzer

My experiment is to change the ui_guage according to the numbers from a csv file. Each number is delayed for 5 sec.(code at end)

Input to csv file is a multi-line msg.payload with three values per line.i.e,

```
 name1, numerical1,numerical11
 name2 numerical2,numerical22,  etc
```

problem: i get no delay of 5sec per message on the gauge...it directly shows the final value present in the last column (i have used a delay node also but still...)

example: display column 3 numericals as indicator with 5 sec delay on gauge.

gauge output: numerical22 (the indicator sets to this position at once)
So, the required per message delay (5 sec) is absent.

I require the delay.

I'am working on IBM cloud lite plan, node red v1.0.6

please review the following code
any help is welcome
if similar is answered before please re-direct me the solution.

To run following code:

1. open Node-RED
2. Click the three lines (top right)
3. import
4. Copy & paste the following flow json code and click "import" button

know more : [Importing and Exporting Flows in Node-RED](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/editor/workspace/import-export)

The code:

```
[
    {
        "id": "c9b43c3a.da2e4",
        "type": "ui_gauge",
        "z": "ac0d0d22.69ebb",
        "name": "",
        "group": "c604d450.9712c8",
        "order": 13,
        "width": "5",
        "height": "5",
        "gtype": "gage",
        "title": "<img height=\"50\" width=\"50\" src=\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Pressure_gauge.svg\"/>",
        "label": "units",
        "format": " {{msg.payload.col3}}",
        "min": 0,
        "max": 10,
        "colors": [
            "#00b500",
            "#e6e600",
            "#ca3838"
        ],
        "seg1": "",
        "seg2": "",
        "x": 840,
        "y": 320,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "c604d450.9712c8",
        "type": "ui_group",
        "z": "",
        "name": "tab1",
        "tab": "c733c61c.6e4828",
        "order": 1,
        "disp": true,
        "width": "12",
        "collapse": false
    },
    {
        "id": "c733c61c.6e4828",
        "type": "ui_tab",
        "z": "",
        "name": "Home1",
        "icon": "dashboard",
        "disabled": false,
        "hidden": false
    }
]
```

Comment: Your sample code is just a ui_gauge node. You should also have a CSV node, delay node, and perhaps a few others to accomplish what you describe.